# How to change location of 'navigation pane' on Sharepoint online Team site

Tags: sharepoint-online

I currently have a team site on SP online, and I've seen other page where the navigation pane is located on the top of the site rather than the left hand side.

For example, I want to go from this:
[image]

and add/transform to this:

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the screenshot you provided, it seems that Top menu is actually Hub navigation.

You will need to register your site as Hub site from SharePoint admin center and then add Hub navigation.

For more info on how to do this, please check below URL: https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-create-hub-sites-in-sharepoint-online/

To hide left menu, you will need to go to Site Settings >> Navigation elements >> Then uncheck "Enable Quick launch".

For more info: https://support.shortpoint.com/support/solutions/articles/1000269709-how-to-hide-quick-launch-left-navigation-from-modern-sharepoint-team-sites

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling quick launch. Go to **Site settings -> Navigation Elements** and then Uncheck Enable Quick Launch option.
[image]

For top navigation if you are not having any item in top navigation then you can add menu items in Global Navigation.

For that go to **Site settings -> Navigation -> Add item under Global Navigation**
[image]